# Make secrete available for all namespaces in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When you create a new namespace in Kubernetes there always will be a `default-token` secret available in it.

```sh
$ kubectl create namespace test
$ kubectl get secrets -n test
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-wh7hv   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      6m10s
```

**Question:**

How can I create a secret that will be always available (as in above example) in newly created namespace?

Answer (score 1):

default-token is used within the cluster and managed by the cluster.
ServiceAccounts are intended to provide an identity for a Kubernetes Pod to be used by its container to authenticate and authorize them when performing API-requests to the Kubernetes API-server. Default ServiceAccount will be created when you create namespace.

Secret resources reside in a namespace. Secrets can only be referenced by Pods in that same namespace.
If you want a way to create your own secret when additional ns created for that you will need an extra utility.

You can write a code to communicate with K8s API
Check the namespace list periodically.
Create a secret when an additional namespace created.